# Log generated IDs from Hibernate insert statements

Tags: hibernate

I already know about Hibernate logging with these two loggers:

- `org.hibernate.SQL` (on `debug` level)
- `org.hibernate.type` (on `trace` level)

These two loggers cover everything I need, except for SQL `INSERT` statements. Their generated IDs are not logged. I stepped through the Hibernate code, but I didn't find any log statements in the area.

Is it possible to log the generated IDs? If so, how?

Comment: `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder` should be giving you the parameter binding values when log level is set to `TRACE`.

Comment: It gives me the parameter bindings _for the query parameters_, but not for the _responses_. The `BasicExtractor` doesn't help either, since it only works for `SELECT` statements, not for `INSERT`.